# Bucle en python, no se cómo hacer para vuelva arriba

Tags: python, bucles

```
 continuar = True
while (continuar == True):
    num = int(input("Digite un numero entre 0 y 10: "))
    if num >= 11 or num < 0:
        respuesta =int(input("Numero invalido por favor digite un numero entre 0 y 10, o digite S para salir: "))
        if respuesta == "S" or respuesta == "s":
            continuar == True
        else:
            continuar== False
    if num >= 0 or num <= 10:
        respuesta = str(input("Digite C para volver o S para salir: "))
        if respuesta == "S" or respuesta == "s":
            continuar == True
        else:
            continuar== False
        if respuesta == "C" or respuesta=="c":
            while (continuar == True):
                num = int(input("Digite un numero entre 0 y 10: "))
```

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que cuando el usuario digite "C" vuelva a preguntar por el número, yo logro hacer que cuando el usuario digite "s" vuelva a preguntar el programa termine, pero no logro hacer que cuando digite la "C" vuelva al principio sin entrar en un bucle infinito

Comment: Tu lógica es complicada. En un input preguntas por un *número*, en otro input preguntas por un *número* o `S` y en otro preguntas por `S` o por `C`. Creo que deberías tener solo un input donde preguntas por el *número* o `S` para salir. Y en base a la respuesta o vuelves a iterar en el `while` o terminas con `continuar = false`

Comment: Un error que se ve es que estás confundiendo `=` con `==`. La asignación de valores a `continuar` debe ser con `=`.

Comment: Estoy viendo este hilo año y medio despues. En ese entonces no existia lower() ???? :D

Answer (score 0):

Tu primer error es que usas mal el operador para asignar el valor a una variable

- El signo `=` se utiliza para hacer una asignación, donde el nombre de la izquierda se le asigna el valor que esta a su derecha después del signo `=`.
- El signo `==` se utiliza para hacer una comparación entre datos, por ejemplo `a==b` se comparan las variables `a` y `b` y devuelve un valor booleano.

En segundo lugar lo que quieres es volver al inicio y para eso creas una variable *de control* pero como el ciclo es un `while` si cambias a `False` es valor de `continuar` el ciclo se romperá y ya no se ejecutara mas, para hacer lo que quieres existe la palabra reservada `continue` la cual hace que el ciclo vuelva al inicio.

Otra cosa es que las comparaciones de la respuesta puede simplificarse convirtiendo la respuesta a minúscula y solo comparar con minúscula, algo que haces erróneamente es en esta linea

```
...
respuesta =int(input("Numero invalido por favor digite un numero entre 0 y 10, o digite S para salir: "))
if respuesta == "S" or respuesta == "s":
    continuar == True
```

Pues conviertes a entero pero pides ó un entero ó un numero, por lo que si se ingresa una letra te saldrá un error y luego comparas la `respuesta` (que es un entero) con un string, lo cual nunca se cumplirá.

```py
while True:
    num = int(input("Digite un numero entre 0 y 10: "))
    if num >= 11 or num < 0:
        respuesta =input("Numero invalido por favor digite un numero entre 0 y 10, o digite S para salir: ")
        if respuesta.lower() == "s":
            break #rompe el ciclo

    elif num >= 0 or num <= 10:
        respuesta = input("Digite C para volver o S para salir: ")
        if respuesta.lower() == "s":
            break
        elif respuesta.lower() =="c":
            continue #vuelve al inicio
```

Comment: jksjkjs estaba escribiendo una respuesta justo cuando la subiste xD

Comment: jaja te gane XD

Comment: me sorprendió no haberla visto antes

Answer (score 0):

Veamos:
Estás cambiando la pregunta de acuerdo a lo ingresado, podrías usar la misma

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
continuar = True
```

no es necesario se puede declarar directamente, pero lo usaré para seguir tu código

```
while continuar:
    num = input("Digite un número entre 0 y 10 o S para salir: ")
```

acá ya aclaramos que puede ser un número o una letra, por lo tanto la tomo directamente como cadena

```
if num not in "sS":
```

si la cadena no es s o S

```
    try:
        if 0 > int(num)  or int(num) > 10 :
            print("Número inválido por favor digite un número entre 0 y 10, o digite S para salir: ")
```

además uso try, para capturar un error, quizá el usuario ingresa "uno" o simplemente otra letra

```
        else:
            print(num) 
            continuar = False
```

simplemente muestro el número, acá puede ir lo que quieras hacer con él

```
    except:
        print("No has introducido un número entero")
```

esto devuelve un mensaje en caso de error

```
else:continuar=False
```

si presiono  s o S termina, para salir de bucles también se puede usar break

Cuidado con "=" es una asignación, o sea le damos un valor y "==" es una comparación.